# visual studio 2012 crashes when starting debugging a c++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I was having a problem the last few days that when I started debugging a c++ project in Visual studio 2012, VS immediately crashed. It offered an option to send report to Microsoft and then restarted. It offered no additional info what might have caused the problem. Before VS crashes, it sometimes displays the dialogbox saying it's loading symbols.

I'm using Windows 8, Visual studio 2012. I have disabled extensions in order to eliminate them from the equation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express (Desktop), and the crashes appear to have stopped after I did the following:

- Unchecked "Always load symbols located next to modules" in the Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols -> Specify Modules window.
- Selected "All modules, unless excluded" (and NOT "Only specified modules") in the Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols window.
- Unchecked "Enable Edit and Continue" in the Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Edit and Continue window.  Not sure if this one is strictly necessary, but it does affect codegen.

Comment: In my case what helped was unchecking the "edit & continue" option.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using Windows 8 my first thought that was that the problem was OS related, since I don't have this issue on Win 7. I didn't find any helpful info on the web that would convince me that it was Win 8 fault.

Before VS crashed, it sometimes displayed the dialog box saying it's loading symbols. This led me to experiment with the settings in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols. I checked permissions on the Cache symbols folder, but it didn't help. I checked "Only specified modules" for the Automatically load symbols for... option. By clicking "Specified modules" link I saw that the list of specified modules was empty so I assumed it won't try to load any modules. I was wrong. I actually had to uncheck the checkbox "always load symbols located next to modules". Unchecking this option solved my crashing problem and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked "enable just my code(managed only)" in the Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
Tested on windows 8 and 10 with VS 2012.